# ASP.NET Looking to count the number of files in a directory

Tags: asp.net

Just wondering how I could get a count on the number of files in a given directory with extension .txt ?

Thanks

Comment: SLaks' answer is best. But you should Google things first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.txt").Count()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("Path", "*.txt").Count()
```

Comment: Nice use of the search pattern overload.

Answer (score 0):

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\");
var count = di.GetFiles("*.txt").Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'Replace C:\ with your directory.
Dim intCount As Integer = (From s As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\") _
                           Where Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(s, 4) = ".txt").Count
```